# Why a row is stacked in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used bootstrap for my website, simply put there are two column enclosed in **col-md-12**, they are **col-md-6**,
They should not be collapsing because enough space is given, why is this happening?

```
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <img  class="centering newReq" src="add-512.png"  height="132" width="142">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning centering btnAdjust">New Request</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <img  class="centering newReq" src="contact.png" height="132" width="142">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning centering btnAdjust">My request</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4 ? can you provide running code example?

Comment: no, its bootstrap 3, and ex would be just 2 images stacked over one another, i thought it would be a padding issue, but its not. :-

Comment: can you share screenshot so we can understand better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `col-md-12` because each row contains each column. Optionally try to use 
`img-responsive` class instead of setting width and height for image.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img class="centering newReq img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" height="132" width="142">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning centering btnAdjust">New Request</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img class="centering newReq img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" height="132" width="142">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning centering btnAdjust">My request</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alpit Anand . If you get solution for the following ans try to mark the answer is helpful. In future other persons also will get same solution.